# Insert text in loading ModalProgressHUD fail

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I include a text under the refreshindicator?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: ModalProgressHUD(child: page(context), inAsyncCall: _loading, progressIndicator: RefreshProgressIndicator(), color: Colors.black),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the ModalProgressHUD in a column with children and then you can add a Text() child after the ModalProgressHUD and inside that column:

```
body: Column(
children: <Widget>[
ModalProgressHUD(),
Text('your text'),
]
),
```

Comment: give me a error
he following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: Try and wrap the column in a SafeArea(), let me know if this doesn't work still

Comment: same error :/
body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ModalProgressHUD(child: page(context), inAsyncCall: _load, progressIndicator: RefreshProgressIndicator(), color: Colors.black),
            Text('your text'),
          ]
      )),